# Change a div color in hiccup

Tags: html, clojure, compojure, hiccup

Is there a way I can set a div background color in hiccup? Here is what I tried so far, with no result:

`[:div {:background-color "#003366"} (escape-html rest)]`

In the html, I see `<div background-color="#663366">` which I do not believe is the correct format for color.

Is there a way to do this in hiccup?

Comment: You might want to look Gaka (found on github).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
[:div {:style "background-color:#003366"} (escape-html rest)]
```

Should do the trick. Might want to consider putting your styles into css files elsewhere though, if doing anything reasonably complex.